# Make x-axis appear in a particular order in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset:

```
data <- c('real','real','real','real','real','pred','pred','pred','pred','pred','real','real','real','real','pred','pred','pred','pred')
threshold <- c('>=1','>=2','>=3','>=4','>=101','>=1','>=2','>=3','>=4','>=101','>=1','>=2','>=3','>=4','>=1','>=2','>=3','>=4')
accuracy <- c(63.4,64.4,65.1,64.3,65.4,62.1,63.6,64.1,65.4,64.8,62.2,63.3,64.4,65.6,63.1,63.8,64.6,65.1)
types<-c('morning','morning','morning','morning','morning','morning','morning','morning','morning','morning','evening','evening','evening','evening','evening','evening','evening','evening')

df <- data.frame(data,threshold,accuracy,types)
```

I want to plot 'data' column as stacked barplot for morning and evening separately. So I use facet wrap. My code for plotting is:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = threshold, y = accuracy)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = data), stat = "identity", color = "white",position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  facet_wrap(~types) + 
  fill_palette("jco")
```

And the plot I get looks like:

[image: plot]

However, as you can see the order of threshold got messed up. I want the order for morning to look like:

```
'>=1','>=2','>=3','>=4','>=101'
```

And the order for evening should be:

```
'>=1','>=2','>=3','>=4'
```

So I have three questions:

1. How can I enforce the order using my code?

2 Also for evening I shouldn't be getting '>=101' so how can I remove that from the plot.

3. Is there a way to make the background white but keep the grid.
4. And on a slightly unrelated note, can you point at a graph type that might be slightly better looking than this? I am new at visualisation so I am still learning.

Insights will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may set order of `threshold` to reorder x axis.

Then add `scales = 'free'` in `facet_wrap` to remove `>=101` in `evening`,

add `theme_bw()` to make background white.

```
df %>%
  mutate(threshold = factor(threshold, levels = c('>=1','>=2','>=3','>=4','>=101'))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = threshold, y = accuracy)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = data), stat = "identity", color = "white",position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  facet_wrap(~types, scales = 'free') +
  theme_bw() + 
  fill_palette("jco")
```

[image]